# LineChart using 2 Dataset in SSRS

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, sql-server-2008-r2, bids

I want to create a line chart using 2 set of values.First value (i.e line) will show open report and second value(i.e line) with show closed report. The x axis will show months and y axis will show number(i.e sum of report). I tried using the following expression in the values
box of chart data but i am getting a straight line.

```
=Sum(Fields!Count.Value, "DataSet1") for line 1
=Sum(Fields!Count.Value, "DataSet2") for line 2
```

I am using cube to create my Dataset.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot combine two datasets in the same chart. You need to combine the data into a single dataset or use the Lookup function if you have a common field between Dataset1 and Dataset2:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee210575(SQL.105).aspx

Comment: Thanks for your reply.
Then in what cases can we use the above expressions?

Comment: If you're asking how to use lookup functions, you can see my blog post series on the topic that begins here: http://blog.datainspirations.com/2010/03/19/sql-server-2008-r2-reporting-services-look-up-look-down-look-all-around-part-i/ Although I don't use a chart example, the principle is the same. Perhaps you will get some inspiration on how to approach your problem.